# How to separate routes from app file in express framework

Tags: node.js, express

For example :

**server.js file**

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  port = 3000,
  routes = require('./app/routes/apiRoutes');

routes(app);

app.listen(port);
```

**routes.js file**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function( app ) {

    var api= require('../controllers/apiController');

    app.route('/get').get(api.get);

};
```

***apiController.js file***

```
 'use strict';

 exports.get = function(req, res) {

     // console.log( req.app ); // access it but it didn't work ?

     // here want to access app to set cookie and changed cookie ?

 };
```

---

if there is another way please help me thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I correct understand your question, with routes you can do something like this:

In `routes.js` file:

```
var router = require('express').Router()

router.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index')
})

module.exports = router
```

In `server.js` file:

```
var mainRoutes = require('./routes.js')
app.use(mainRoutes)
```

Best way (in my opinion) to use controllers from another file it's use `exports.functionName` notation:

In `someController.js` file:

```
exports.homePage = function(req, res) {
    res.render('index')
}
```

So, your router will looks like this:

```
var router = require('express').Router()
var someController = require('./someController.js')

router.get('/home', someController.homePage)

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 1):

Do different way, use route in `app.use`

`app.js`:

```
const
  express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  port = 3000,
  routes = require('./app/routes/apiRoutes');

app.use(routes);

app.listen(port);
```

`apiRoutes.js`:

```
const 
  router = require('express').Router(),
  apiController = require('../controllers/apiController');


router.get(
  '/get', 
  apiController.get);

module.exports = router;
```

Check this example: [app.js](https://bitbucket.org/num8er/citymag-az-website/src/e4a0a804c1ca6c4ca2814810cd071a1e4541c59d/app.js?at=master) , [some route file](https://bitbucket.org/num8er/citymag-az-website/src/e4a0a804c1ca6c4ca2814810cd071a1e4541c59d/routes/api/menu.js?at=master)